# Filter an array with a callback - for single & multidimensional arrays

Tags: filters, callbacks

I've a filter attached, that allows modifying an array:

```
$data = apply_filters( 'wpse_example_filter', $data );
```

The problem is, that the data can be a single or multidimensional array:

```
// single:
'SINGLE' => array(
    // some data
)
// multidimensional:
'MULTI' => array(
     0 => array(
         // some data
     )
     1 => array(
         // some data
     )
)
```

**Question:** What's the easiest way to loop through the data of one of those arrays (inside my callback), without knowing if I got a single or multidimensional array and without creating another callback function?

**In other words:** How would I write a recursive filter callback?

Comment: Have you tried using the array_walk_recursive function in PHP?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: @Otto Just add an answer - upvotes are real.

Comment: That wasn't an answer in and of itself, I was asking for clarification. Your particular situation may not be suited to using that function, since I don't know exactly what you're trying to do with the data.

Comment: Imagine above filter to be in some 3rd party plugin. Below array (`SINGLE/MULTI`) is what is inside `$data`. I'm then writing another plugin to modify the `$data`, array by array - or just a single one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your answer is very interesting and I like it, I still want to post another proposal, just let you have another choice :)

IMHO, if the data contains only simple fields, like:

```
array(
    'name' => 'my name',
    'address' => 'my address',
    'phone' => '01234',
);
```

then you can use the code below:

```
add_filter( 'wpse63692_example_filter', 'wpse63692_example_cb' );

function wpse63692_example_cb( $data )
{
    foreach ( $data as $key => $value )
    {
        // Recursively apply filters to sub array
        if ( is_array( $value ) )
            $data[$key] = apply_filters( current_filter(), $value );
    }

    // Do something with $data

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: +1 :) I hope you don't mind the edit. One sidenote: `is_array()` will also trigger sub-sub-sub-arrays and fail in this case (where one wants to not touch the sub array.

Comment: I like your `current_filter` function! Thanks for editing for me :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've found so far.

The **trick** is, that I'm using a non existent 2<sup>nd</sup> argument named `$recursive` to determine if I'm in a recursive loop or not. The default value is `false`, so the `$is_multiple` loop gets triggered. I'm then passing a `true` to the function call, to disallow a loop through possibly present sub-sub-arrays.

The only reason why this is possible, is that the filter/action API doesn't start crying when I got *more* arguments for my function, than `apply_filters()` has.

```
function wpse63692_example_cb( $data, $recursive = false )
{
    $result = $data;
    if ( 1 < count( $data ) AND ! $recursive )
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ( $data as $key => $value )
            $result[ $key ] = call_user_func( __FUNCTION__, $value, true );
    }

    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'wpse63692_example_filter', 'wpse63692_example_cb' );
```